# Rails authenticate_customer before_filter Jquerymobile "error loading page"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-mobile

I'm using Rails3 and jquerymobile. When I click a link like /edit_profile, for annonymous users should redirect to login page. Jquery mobile shows a popup with the message "error loading page".

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that jquery mobile uses AJAX calls for the link_to methods, and rails doesn't support that. 
In my case, I made it a regular link_to (non-AJAX based) by adding the following to my link

```
data-ajax="false"
```

In the link_to options, i.e:

```
link_to 'Model', {:controller => "models", :action => "any_action"}, "data-ajax" => "false"
```

I hope that helps someone someday.
Cheers! 
Yohann.